# Problem with import gcp secrets with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform

I´m using gcp secrets manager (cloud service), and in my code I use the package @google-cloud/secret-manager to get them.

like this:

```
  const [version] = await client.accessSecretVersion({
    name: name_here
  })

    const responsePayload = Dotenv.parse(version?.payload?.data.toString());

    await this.setDatabase(responsePayload)
```

Well after that I use this functions setDatabase to put this payload on a config object, that I created more above in the code.

The problems is that, in other scripts, is imported this config object before the load of the setDatabase() in order to connect knex with dabatase, but in time of load the imports the config object is still blank.

Maybe somes pics will clarify:

[config File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtYiJ.png)

[import in other script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxzAu.png)

[console.log of config.database before loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0Oxm.png)

[console.log of config in other moment after loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLacH.png)

Anyone has a tip for it?

Answer (score 1):

well I would put all of your initialization tasks into one place, and do them in the sequence you want, so there isn't a cross dependency between common includes.  It will give you a cleaner result when your init code is isolated like this.

Comment: I don't get it, can you give me an example?

Comment: right now all your code that is doing these types of tasks (creating global variables, calling constructors, initializing objects, and so on) are spread in multiple files.  I suggest putting them in one file, your initialization file, and put the code in an initialization function, which you can structure how you want to ensure execution order is what you want.